# How to add Azure AD Application using application identifier

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am having difficulty logging in to a Microsoft site using my Azure AD (Work) account.

After successfully authenticating, I get the error:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '3075c070-b4d6-4bba-88c3-bcc51c74a2f4' was
>   not found in the directory '{my-directory}'. This can happen if the
>   application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant
>   or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your
>   authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I have gone into my Azure AD tenant and searched for an application with that Id so I can add it, but it returns no results.

I am able to authenticate if I use an account that has a Microsoft Account, however, when I get to the Microsoft page, I get an error saying I need to log in using the same email account that the account was registered under.

Unfortunately, the work account I need to use does not have an associated Microsoft Account.

I think a solution to this would be to add the Application into my tenant, but not sure how to find the application with ID only.

Comment: This is a mis-configuration of the app, which would need to be resolved for you to be able to sign in with an Azure AD account (assuming the app publisher intended to allow Azure AD accounts). (I've notified the app owners for this app to the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you can not add the application into your tenant manually. When you successfully login in to this application, this application will exist in your tenant under enterprise application.

But it seems that this application only allows Microsoft account to login.